# [[:space:]] is not matching newline in sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace all words "BBB" ins a file to "XXX" But for some reason I cant seem to make `[[:space:]]` match the newline:

```
[root@REDHAT]# cat file
AAA
BBB
 BBB
CCC

[root@REDHAT]# sed 's/[[:space:]]BBB/XXX/g' file
AAA
BBB
XXX
CCC
```

Note how only the second `BBB` was replaced; `[[:space:]]` didn't match the newline preceding the first occurrence.

Comment: sed by default operates line by line... what is your expected output?

Comment: Wouldn't just `s/BBB/XXX/g` work?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Actually its for a more complicated Sed statement where I am searching for a particular word and Comment the line out.

Comment: A good example would contain representative input, ideally your real input, because now, your question can be solved quite simply (replace all `BBB` with `XXX`), but that's not actually what you want to do.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Simply replacing wouldnt work if i would not want to replace BBB with XXX, if BBB appears in a part of a word. For example I do not want to replace it if the word in the file is like BBB1 or like BBBB.

Comment: I understand that, but that should be part of the question, ideally including `BBB1` in the input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) points out:

- `sed` reads its input line by line by default.
- Each line read doesn't include the trailing newline,

  - so the only thing `[[:space:]]` can possibly match is a space or a tab char.

Perhaps the following command does what you want (works with BSD Sed and GNU Sed):

```sh
$ sed -E 's/(^|[[:blank:]])BBB/XXX/' file
AAA
XXX
XXX
CCC
```

- `(^|[[:blank:]])` matches either the beginning of a line (`^`) or a single tab or space character (`[[:blank:]]`).
- I've omitted the `g` option, under the assumption that there's at most *one* `BBB` per line.

Comment: @ImranRentia: Thanks - that's all that's needed - the accepted status now tells future readers that this answer solved the problem. (Up-voting in addition to accepting is optional anyway - once you have enough rep, you can choose to do it if you think an answer is especially helpful.)